# what is the equivalent of kernel32.dll in ubuntu?

Tags: c#, linux, ipc, ubuntu-16.04, named-pipes

Hi I have developed sample application in c3 and cpp in windows environment. This application achieves Named pipes between these programs to communicate. I have `[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]` command in my cpp program. when i compile my c# progaram i get below error.

```
Enter the message
Unhandled Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'kernel32.dll': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at consoleapp.NamedPipeServer.CreateNamedPipe(String pipeName, UInt32 dwOpenMode, UInt32 dwPipeMode, UInt32 nMaxInstances, UInt32 nOutBufferSize, UInt32 nInBufferSize, UInt32 nDefaultTimeOut, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes)
   at consoleapp.NamedPipeServer.ListenForClients() in /home/niranjan/consoleapp/NamedPipeServer.cs:line 66
   at System.Threading.Thread.ThreadMain_ThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'kernel32.dll': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at consoleapp.NamedPipeServer.CreateNamedPipe(String pipeName, UInt32 dwOpenMode, UInt32 dwPipeMode, UInt32 nMaxInstances, UInt32 nOutBufferSize, UInt32 nInBufferSize, UInt32 nDefaultTimeOut, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes)
   at consoleapp.NamedPipeServer.ListenForClients() in /home/niranjan/consoleapp/NamedPipeServer.cs:line 66
   at System.Threading.Thread.ThreadMain_ThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

Below is my c# files. I have created .Net core(2.0) console application in ubuntu.
Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace consoleapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            NamedPipeServer PServer1 = new NamedPipeServer(@"\\.\pipe\myNamedPipe1",0);
            NamedPipeServer PServer2 = new NamedPipeServer(@"\\.\pipe\myNamedPipe2",1);

            PServer1.Start();
            PServer2.Start();

            string Ms="Start";
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the message");
                Ms = Console.ReadLine();
                PServer2.SendMessage(Ms, PServer2.clientse);
            } while (Ms != "quit");

            PServer1.StopServer();
            PServer2.StopServer();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my NamedPipeServer.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace consoleapp
{
    public class NamedPipeServer
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateNamedPipe(
           String pipeName,
           uint dwOpenMode,
           uint dwPipeMode,
           uint nMaxInstances,
           uint nOutBufferSize,
           uint nInBufferSize,
           uint nDefaultTimeOut,
           IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int ConnectNamedPipe(
           SafeFileHandle hNamedPipe,
           IntPtr lpOverlapped);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int DisconnectNamedPipe(
           SafeFileHandle hNamedPipe);

        public const uint DUPLEX = (0x00000003);
        public const uint FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED = (0x40000000);

        public class Client
        {
            public SafeFileHandle handle;
            public FileStream stream;
        }

        public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
        public Client clientse =null;

        public string pipeName;
        Thread listenThread;
        SafeFileHandle clientHandle;
        public int ClientType;

        public NamedPipeServer(string PName,int Mode)
        {
            pipeName = PName;
            ClientType = Mode;//0 Reading Pipe, 1 Writing Pipe

        }

        public void Start()
        {
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.listenThread.Start();
        }
        private void ListenForClients()
        {
            while (true)
            {

                clientHandle =CreateNamedPipe(this.pipeName,DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,0,255,BUFFER_SIZE,BUFFER_SIZE,0,IntPtr.Zero);

                //could not create named pipe
                if (clientHandle.IsInvalid)
                    return;

                int success = ConnectNamedPipe(clientHandle, IntPtr.Zero);

                //could not connect client
                if (success == 0)
                    return;

                clientse = new Client();
                clientse.handle = clientHandle;
                clientse.stream = new FileStream(clientse.handle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, BUFFER_SIZE, true);

                if (ClientType == 0)
                {
                    Thread readThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Read));
                    readThread.Start();
                }
            }
        }
        private void Read()
        {
            //Client client = (Client)clientObj;
            //clientse.stream = new FileStream(clientse.handle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, BUFFER_SIZE, true);
            byte[] buffer = null;
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

            while (true)
            {

                int bytesRead = 0;

                try
                {
                    buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                    bytesRead = clientse.stream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                }
                catch
                {
                    //read error has occurred
                    break;
                }

                //client has disconnected
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                    break;

                //fire message received event
                //if (this.MessageReceived != null)
                //    this.MessageReceived(clientse, encoder.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                int ReadLength = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
                {
                    if (buffer[i].ToString("x2") != "cc")
                    {
                        ReadLength++;
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
                if (ReadLength > 0)
                {
                    byte[] Rc = new byte[ReadLength];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, Rc, 0, ReadLength);

                    Console.WriteLine("C# App: Received " + ReadLength +" Bytes: "+ encoder.GetString(Rc, 0, ReadLength));
                    buffer.Initialize();
                }

            }

            //clean up resources
            clientse.stream.Close();
            clientse.handle.Close();

        }
        public void SendMessage(string message, Client client)
        {

                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] messageBuffer = encoder.GetBytes(message);

                if (client.stream.CanWrite)
                {
                    client.stream.Write(messageBuffer, 0, messageBuffer.Length);
                    client.stream.Flush();
                }


        }
        public void StopServer()
        {
            //clean up resources

            DisconnectNamedPipe(this.clientHandle);


            this.listenThread.Abort();
        }

    }
}
```

below is my cpp programe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

unsigned long __stdcall NET_RvThr(void * pParam) ;
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc() ;
HANDLE hPipe1,hPipe2; 
BOOL Finished;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Pipe Init Data
    char buf[100];

    LPTSTR lpszPipename1 = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\myNamedPipe1"); 
    LPTSTR lpszPipename2 = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\myNamedPipe2"); 

    DWORD cbWritten;
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(buf);

    //Thread Init Data
    DWORD threadId;
    HANDLE hThread = NULL;

    BOOL Write_St=TRUE;

    Finished=FALSE;




    hPipe1=CreateFile(lpszPipename1,    GENERIC_WRITE ,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,NULL);
    hPipe2=CreateFile(lpszPipename2,    GENERIC_READ ,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,NULL);


     if ((hPipe1 == NULL || hPipe1 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)||(hPipe2 == NULL || hPipe2 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE))
    { 
        printf("Could not open the pipe  - (error %d)\n",GetLastError());

    }
     else
     {

         hThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, &NET_RvThr, NULL, 0, NULL);
         do
         {
             printf ("Enter your message: ");
             scanf ("%s",buf);  
             if (strcmp (buf,"quit") == 0)
                Write_St=FALSE;
             else
             {
                WriteFile(hPipe1, buf, dwBytesToWrite, &cbWritten, NULL);
                memset(buf,0xCC,100);

             }

        }while(Write_St);

        CloseHandle(hPipe1);
        CloseHandle(hPipe2);
        Finished=TRUE;
     }

     getchar();


}
unsigned long __stdcall NET_RvThr(void * pParam) {
    BOOL fSuccess; 
    char chBuf[100];
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(chBuf);
    DWORD cbRead;
    int i;

    while(1)
    {
        fSuccess =ReadFile( hPipe2,chBuf,dwBytesToWrite,&cbRead, NULL); 
        if(fSuccess)
        {
            printf("C++ App: Received %d Bytes : ",cbRead);
            for(i=0;i<cbRead;i++)
                printf("%c",chBuf[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        if (! fSuccess && GetLastError() != ERROR_MORE_DATA) 
        {
            printf("Can't Read\n");
            if(Finished)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out ubuntu equivalent of kernal32.dll. Can someone help me to figure out this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There is no equivalent in linux. AFAIK

Comment: "command in my cpp program" Which is it? Cpp or C#? Why don't you use System.IO.Pipes? http://voices.canonical.com/tag/named%20pipes/

Comment: Thanks. It is cpp program. I will post cpp programehere.

Comment: It is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988483/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-of-kernel32-dll

Comment: I tried with  [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", SetLastError = true)] but i got msvcrt.dll System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'msvcrt.dll': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the equivalent of kernel32.dll in Ubuntu?**

`Kernel32.dll` is a Windows-specific library. You won't find it on other operating systems such as Ubuntu (unless you use some emulation layer such as Wine). Thus, you cannot use your platform-specific code on Ubuntu.

**So, how do I use named pipes in a platform-independent way?**

Luckily, the .NET Framework designers solved that problem for you: .NET Core 2.0 includes the [System.IO.Pipes Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes?view=netcore-2.0), which contains managed wrappers for interprocess communication through named pipes.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day.  So instead of writing   [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] what should i write?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole: Instead of `[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateNamedPipe(... etc. pp. ...)`, you look into the documentation of the System.IO.Pipes namespace and find a replacement method there (that creates a named pipe). Repeat for all other methods that include `DllImport`. Note that there might not be a direct replacement (since the .NET methods probably won't return SafeFileHandle but some other, managed class), so it might be necessary to slightly rewrite the rest of your code as well.

Comment: So for example NamedPipeServerStream pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe") will bethe replacement of  public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateNamedPipe right?

Comment: Can you please share on e method as an example?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole: There is some example code on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication. Unfortunately, I don't have enough personal experience with them to be able to help with translating your code.